# Closed form for $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4\,x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, definite-integrals, closed-form

I encountered this integral in my calculations:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4\,x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}\mathrm dx=2\int_0^\infty\frac{x\log\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4\,x^2}\right)}{e^x-1}\mathrm dx=6.041880938342236884944983747836284...,$$

but could not find a closed-form representation for it. I tried to replace a constant factor $\frac{\pi^2}4$ with a parameter and take a derivative, that made the integral look simpler, but I still was not successful in solving it.

I also tried to find possible closed forms using [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=6.041880938342236884944983747836284&lookup_type=simple) and [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6.041880938342236884944983747836284) but they did not find anything.

Could you please help me to find a closed form (even using non-elementary special functions), if it exists?

Comment: why do you need a close form so badly, may I ask? why do you think such a thing exists?

Comment: I am not sure it exists, but if it exists I want to know it. Closed forms are easier to manipulate, sometimes closed forms of different integrals or sums contain terms that cancel each other etc. 

I found this paper very useful and interesting: [_J. M. Borwein, R. E. Crandall, "Closed Forms: What They Are and Why We Care"._](http://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/closed-form.pdf)

Comment: Plus, there is always the frivolous answer that they are fun and challenging to arrive at.

Comment: A solution to the same integral was given on another forum, here - http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/post456.html#p456

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A closed form indeed exists for this integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4\,x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}\mathrm dx=\pi^2\left(\log\frac{\pi\,A^9\sqrt{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})^2}-\frac{9}{8}\right)+2\,\pi\,C,$$
where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html) and $C$ is the [Catalan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html).

A more general result:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}\mathrm dx=8\,\pi^2\psi^{(-2)}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2\pi}\right)-\frac{a}2\left(1+\log\frac{4\pi^2}{a}\right)-2\pi\sqrt{a}\left(1+2\log\Gamma\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2\pi}\right)\right),$$
where $\psi^{(-2)}(z)$ is the [generalized polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygamma_function).

The proof is based on [Binet's second formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html), but I still need to sort out some details.

Comment: Here is a method http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/post456.html#p456

Answer (score 1):

$$ \text{firstly put} ,  x \to 4\pi^2 x^2 $$
$$ \to I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{16x^2}\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1} 8\pi^2xdx $$
now using
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{16x^2}\right)=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}dy$$
got
$$ I=16\pi^2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} y \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \frac{1}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx dy $$
using the derevative of arctan function
$$ \frac{-\partial}{\partial y} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} $$
give us
$$ I=-16\pi^2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx dy $$
using Binet's formula
$$ \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx =\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln \Gamma(y)-\left( y-\frac{1}{2} \right)\ln y+y-\frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi) \right) $$
therefroe
$$ I=-8\pi^2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} y \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\ln \Gamma(y)-\left( y-\frac{1}{2} \right)\ln y+y-\frac{1}{2} \ln(2\pi) \right)  dy $$
by derivative we got
$$ I=-8\pi^2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} y \left(\psi(y)+\frac{1}{2y}-\ln y\right)  dy=-8\pi^2(I_1+I_2) $$
where
$$ I_1=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} y \psi(y) dy$$
$$ I_2=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} \left(\frac{1}{2}-y\ln y\right)  dy $$
its easy to show that
$$ I_1=\frac{1}{4} \ln \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\psi^{(-2)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{4} \ln \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{9}{8} \ln A - \frac{C}{4\pi}-\frac{\ln(2\pi)}{8}$$
$$ I_2=\frac{9}{64}+\frac{\ln2}{16} $$
therefore
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\pi^2}{4x}\right)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}-1}dx=\pi^2 \ln \left(\frac{\pi A^9 \sqrt{2}}{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} \right)+2\pi C-\frac{9}{8}\pi^2 $$